# Confirm current power plan via python

Tags: python, powercfg

I'm trying to automate checking what the current power plan is and then return a response based on that. Here's what I have:

```
import subprocess

plan = subprocess.call("powercfg -getactivescheme")
if 'Balanced' in plan:  
    print Success
```

When I run this I get "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns a code, which means the status code of the executed command.

I also recommend you calling subprocess like this:

```
subprocess.call(["powercfg", "-getactivescheme"])
```

As I guess you want to get the output in a variable I recommend you using [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which returns a string containing the output of a command:

```
output = subproccess.check_output(["powercfg", "-getactivescheme"])
```

Then you can do the checking:

```
if 'Balanced' in output:  
    print 'Success'
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Was just writing a very similar answer. Beat me to it! :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for the help!